# Reducing audio delay from redirecting input to output

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, realtime

I tried using the solution presented in a [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2719/how-do-i-output-my-audio-input) for redirecting my audio input to my output, but the problem is that there's a very noticeable lag.  It's especially obvious to me because I have my keyboard's audio out hooked up to my soundcard's in, which is then redirected to a different audio out device on my computer.  I'd say there's at least 1/8th sec lag introduced.

`gst-launch pulsesrc ! pulsesink`

`nice -n -15 gst-launch pulsesrc ! pulsesink` does not help any.

Any alternative ways that might work better?

Comment: Nicing it to the max didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looking up JACK for low-latency audio in Ubuntu (or any other Linux for that matter) It allows for the low level redirecting you're after, but you may have to force it to work...