# How to switch audio output between laptop speakers and docking station, or at least disable jack sense?

Tags: 11.04, sound, pulseaudio

I got an HP 8530w Elitebook laptop which is in a docking station quite often. When it's in the docking station, I'd like to be able to **choose if sound comes from my built-in laptop speakers** (for watching a quick video) **or from the audio out jack in the back of the docking station**, which is connected to my stereo (for movies and music listening).
I can switch by physically unplugging the audio cable in the docking station, but that's neither elegant nor convenient.

I know this **is possible hardware-wise**, because up until about 9.04 or so, this worked with a little trick (pressing the hardware-mute button while hovering the speaker icon in the gnome-panel changed between speaker and dock output). I knew then that this must have been a bug. After some upgrade (no way to tell which) this stopped working.

I only see one output device (Internal Audio Analogue Stereo) in either sound preferences or in `pavucontrol`.

There's **no jack sense entry in `alsamixer`**. There's a "dock" entry where I can mute the output out of the dock connector, but the internal speakers stay silent.

My hardware (touch) mute button has no effect (though it changes colour), doesn't bother me though. The hardware volume adjust buttons work as expected.

output of `aplay -l`:

```
List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices 
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: AD198x Analog [AD198x Analog]
Subdevices: 0/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

output of `head -n 1 /proc/asound/card*/codec#*`:

```
==> /proc/asound/card0/codec#0 <==
Codec: Analog Devices AD1984A

==> /proc/asound/card0/codec#1 <==
Codec: LSI ID 1040
```

Audio device (output of `lspci -nn|egrep 'ultimedia|udio|sound|AC97|ac97|EMU'`)

`00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller [8086:293e] (rev 03)`

Any ideas?

Comment: Any more info I should add?

Comment: Possibly related? http://askubuntu.com/questions/100/sound-comes-out-of-my-speakers-even-when-headphones-are-plugged-in and http://askubuntu.com/questions/2719/how-do-i-output-my-audio-input

Comment: My hp laptop has had some minor audio issues for a while that evidenced after some kernel upgrades(weird behaviours from the sensor buttons at the top of the keyboard and jack sense requiring changing the volume).  I just accept it as trying to get more compatibility at the expense of ease of use.  Free is free right?

Comment: Does nobody have a clue?

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards

Comment: Well, it's still viable insofar it has remained unsolved, I still got the problem I describe. As to the probability that someone will answer it, not even a bounty helped with that, so I find it hard to judge that. "too localized", though? I can't imagine I'm the only one with problems with jack sense...

Comment: @fossfreedom: So, I just got a "Popular question" badge for this question. Is it still regarded as "too localized"?

Comment: ... its almost been a year - so that badge is likely to occur - web scanners etc.  Do you want me to reopen this? - if you can add to the question - for example, you've tried 11.10 & 12.04 and the problem still occurs.  Have you ever filed a bug report?  Drop a comment or hit the flag link with a reply.  thanks.

Comment: OK, didn't think about web scanners. Yeah, this is still occurring in 11.10 (will test 12.04 when released). I originally searched for bug reports on this but didn't find anything fitting. Never mind for now, I think I've given up on this anyway, if I file a bug in the future, I'll flag it.

Comment: Still an issue with 14.x or 15.x?