# How to change audio input to output?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I have one audio output and two audio inputs on my computer. But I have one microphone, stereo reproductors and headphones. In windows Realtek driver I could simple change the audio input to output, now I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and PulseAudio. Is there any option to change the input to output and conversely?

Comment: use this link it will solve your problem 
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/44966/how-to-switch-audio-output-between-laptop-speakers-and-docking-station-or-at-le?rq=1

Comment: Check [How do you set a default audio output device in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038490/how-do-you-set-a-default-audio-output-device-in-ubuntu-18-04/1038492#1038492)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that by going to : system settings -> sound. and change the default hardware used in input or output.