# No sound output through HDMI

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, hdmi

I was trying to connect my computer to my tv with hdmi and no sound would go through. When I click on the sound settings in the volume control nothing happens and I can't find it in the system setting either. Can anyone help me?

Comment: In the sound settings you should be able to select HDMI as the output. Can't you open system settings? Is that the problem?

Comment: Can you add more info about what you have already tried? what settings did you try to change in the volume control?

Comment: And which Ubuntu version is it?

Answer (score 1):

Referencing my own answer on a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/a/1076814/234305)

open `PulseAudio Volume Control`

Once you've opened PulseAudio Volume Control, choose the `configuration` (the last tab), then select the output and/or input you want to use from the `profile` dropdown menu. [It should look similar to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5BBw.png).

If this doesn't solve the problem, verify that you get sound from other outputs, try a different HDMI cable Verify that whatever device you are trying to play sound through is working, volume is turned up, audio output is connected etc.).

---

`PulseAudio Volume Control` can also be used to adjust volume levels for each input, output, system sounds and applications that are currently in use.

Here's a [post](https://linuxhint.com/pulse_audio_sounds_ubuntu/) from Linuxhint with more info on PulseAudio.