# OSError: No Default Input Device Available on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound, python3

I'm running a speech recognition program, and it comes up with

> OSError: No Default Input Device Available.

How do I set a default input and output device?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you set a default audio output device in Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038490/how-do-you-set-a-default-audio-output-device-in-ubuntu-18-04)