# Selected Sound Output Device Not Persisting Between Reboots in gnome-control-center

Tags: gnome, sound, pulseaudio, gnome-control-center, 19.10

Each time I reboot Ubuntu 19.10, I have to open gnome-control-center and set the sound output device back to my Laptop's Built-in speakers. Otherwise, it will typically default to DisplayPort devices that don't even have speakers.

[image]

Which file are these settings saved to? I'm thinking that maybe that file is corrupted and that if I delete that file maybe Ubuntu 19.10 will start remembering my sound output preferences. I'm also open to other suggestions.

Comment: Sébastien Bacher informed me that this is a known [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1847570).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have had the bug report suggestions setup this way for along time as sound is always routed to TV and I don't want it to switch to tinny laptop speakers.

Use `sudo -H gedit /etc/pulse/default.pa` and find the lines:

```
load-module module-switch-on-port-available
load-module module-switch-on-connect
```

Change them to:

```
#load-module module-switch-on-port-available
#load-module module-switch-on-connect
```

Save the file and use: `pulseaudio -k`

**Note 1:** It's been reported that plain `sudo` now performs like `sudo -H` in 19.04 but caution dictates using later method.

**Note 2:** Earlier versions of Ubuntu will only have the first configuration line.

Comment: The downside of this patch is that plugging in headphones or bluetooth speaker no longer switches automatically.