# Can you remove a device from the Output Audio Devices list?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, hdmi, 19.10

I am using ubuntu 19.10 and one of my monitors is connected through HDMI to my computer, but it does not have any speakers.

However, a lot of times, whenever I unplug my USB headset or reboot my computer, the HDMI audio output gets selected as the default device and I have to manually change it.

Since it won't ever be an audio output, is there a way to remove it from the list altogether?

Comment: See the answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183052/selected-sound-output-device-not-persisting-between-reboots-in-gnome-control-cen