# How to stop version 19.10 from changing sound/audio output device?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, hdmi, 19.10

My sound output device keeps changing from my desired selection of "alsa_output.usb-Bose_Corporation_Bose_USB_Audio-00.analog-surround-50" to "alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra4".

I have already specified that I want the Bose device to be the default audio sink via `set-default-sink` (see the asterisk):

```
2 sink(s) available.
  * index: 42
    name: <alsa_output.usb-Bose_Corporation_Bose_USB_Audio-00.analog-surround-50>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: RUNNING
    suspend cause: (none)
    priority: 9049
    volume: front-left: 0 /   0% / -inf dB,   front-right: 0 /   0% / -inf dB,   rear-left: 25754 /  39% / -24.34 dB,   rear-right: 0 /   0% / -inf dB,   front-center: 0 /   0% / -inf dB
            balance -1.00
    base volume: 65687 / 100% / 0.06 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 23.27 ms
    max request: 10 KiB
    max rewind: 10 KiB
    monitor source: 44
    sample spec: s16le 5ch 48000Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right,front-center
                 Surround 5.0
    used by: 1
    linked by: 1
    configured latency: 23.22 ms; range is 0.50 .. 1820.44 ms
    card: 6 <alsa_card.usb-Bose_Corporation_Bose_USB_Audio-00>
    module: 29
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "USB Audio"
        alsa.id = "USB Audio"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "2"
        alsa.card_name = "Bose USB Audio"
        alsa.long_card_name = "Bose Corporation Bose USB Audio at usb-0000:00:14.0-10, full speed"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:10:1.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-10/1-10:1.0/sound/card2"
        udev.id = "usb-Bose_Corporation_Bose_USB_Audio-00"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.vendor.id = "05a7"
        device.vendor.name = "Bose Corp."
        device.product.id = "1020"
        device.product.name = "Bose USB Audio"
        device.serial = "Bose_Corporation_Bose_USB_Audio"
        device.string = "surround50:2"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "873810"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "436900"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-surround-50"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Surround 5.0"
        device.description = "Bose USB Audio Analog Surround 5.0"
        alsa.mixer_name = "USB Mixer"
        alsa.components = "USB05a7:1020"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-usb"
    ports:
        analog-output: Analog Output (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:

    active port: <analog-output>
    index: 68
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra4>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE
    priority: 9030
    volume: front-left: 12074 /  18% / -44.08 dB,   front-right: 12074 /  18% / -44.08 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max request: 0 KiB
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    monitor source: 70
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 371.52 ms
    card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1>
    module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "HDMI 4"
        alsa.id = "HDMI 4"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "10"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xdb560000 irq 159"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:00.1"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "1002"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]"
        device.product.id = "ab08"
        device.product.name = "Polaris 22 HDMI Audio"
        device.string = "hdmi:1,4"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "hdmi-stereo-extra4"
        device.profile.description = "Digital Stereo (HDMI 5)"
        device.description = "Polaris 22 HDMI Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI 5)"
        alsa.mixer_name = "ATI R6xx HDMI"
        alsa.components = "HDA:1002aa01,00aa0100,00100700"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        hdmi-output-4: HDMI / DisplayPort 5 (priority 5500, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                device.product.name = "SAMSUNG"
    active port: <hdmi-output-4>
```

No matter what though, Ubuntu keeps switching back to the HDMI audio device at some arbitrary time. Sound continues to play through the Bose speakers but the main volume control won't change the volume. I then have change the device in Settings > Sound > Output.

Can I disable the HDMI device?

Has anyone else had this problem?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you set a default audio output device in Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038490/how-do-you-set-a-default-audio-output-device-in-ubuntu-18-04)?

Comment: I had already set the default audio device using pacmd set-default-sink "...". But it kept switching back to the HDMI sink. The answer below has been accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `blacklist snd_hda_codec_hdmi` to your /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf file, reboot.

That's how I disabled my HDMI output on my 19.10 install.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think that did the trick! I don't see the HDMI device in the Settings GUI. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped :D

Comment: I have no idea why it would try to do this every time, even after I configured it.... Stupid Ubuntu...

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
blacklist snd_hda_codec_hdmi
```

to your `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` file, and reboot.

Not really friendly, but did it for me, after some other failed attempts to solve it. Whenever my NUC media center went to dim the screens and came back after getting focus, it changed the audio outputs from S/PDIF to HDMI, which was annoying.