# pactl - Default Input - No Such entity

Tags: 18.04, sound, microphone, input

Referring to the [Ask-Ubuntu link here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038490/how-do-you-set-a-default-audio-output-device-in-ubuntu-18-04), I am hoping to use the following CL term to make an input the default input using `pactl set-default-sink`. Despite what I believe is proper syntax, I continue to get `Failure: No such entity`.

So for example if I run

```
pactl list short sources
1   alsa_output.pci-0000_09_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1.monitor module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
2   alsa_output.pci-0000_0b_00.4.iec958-stereo.monitor  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
3   alsa_input.pci-0000_0b_00.4.analog-stereo   module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
23  alsa_input.usb-JOUNIVO_JV601_JOUNIVO_JV601_20180508-00.analog-stereo    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   RUNNING
24  alsa_input.usb-HDA_Webcam_USB_HDA_Webcam_USB_HDA_Webcam_USB-02.iec958-stereo    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   RUNN
```

And then:

```
pactl set-default-sink 'alsa_input.usb-JOUNIVO_JV601_JOUNIVO_JV601_20180508-00.analog-stereo'
Failure: No such entity
```

Any advice on what I may be doing wrong would be highly appreciated.

[The following commands also yield No such entity]

```
pactl set-default-sink alsa_input.usb-JOUNIVO_JV601_JOUNIVO_JV601_20180508-00.analog-stereo



pactl set-default-sink "alsa_input.usb-JOUNIVO_JV601_JOUNIVO_JV601_20180508-00.analog-stereo
```

Comment: Can you run "pactl list short sinks" instead to display the list?

Answer (score 2):

I think the command you are looking for is

```
pactl set-default-source alsa_input.usb-JOUNIVO_JV601_JOUNIVO_JV601_20180508-00.analog-stereo
```

I found the command with `man pactl`