# Setting default sound device on startup

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, startup, default

I followed the post @singrium made ([How do you set a default audio output device in Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038490/how-do-you-set-a-default-audio-output-device-in-ubuntu-18-04)) and it works. Almost...

On startup the computer defaults to the USB audio input/output from my dell dock no matter what I do. If I unplug the dock and plug it back in, the input/output devices are set as expected (internal speakers and mic).  Is there a fix for startup? I'm using names in the default.pa.

Here are my sources:

```
pactl list short sources
1   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
2   alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo   module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
3   alsa_output.usb-Generic_USB_Audio_200901010001-00.HiFi__hw_Dock_1__sink.monitor module-alsa-card.c  s24le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
4   alsa_output.usb-Generic_USB_Audio_200901010001-00.HiFi__hw_Dock__sink.monitor   module-alsa-card.c  s24le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
5   alsa_input.usb-Generic_USB_Audio_200901010001-00.HiFi__hw_Dock__source  module-alsa-card.c  s24le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
```

and sinks:

```
pactl list short sinks
1   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
2   alsa_output.usb-Generic_USB_Audio_200901010001-00.HiFi__hw_Dock_1__sinkmodule-alsa-card.c   s24le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
3   alsa_output.usb-Generic_USB_Audio_200901010001-00.HiFi__hw_Dock__sink   module-alsa-card.c  s24le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
```

In /etc/pulse/default.pa I have commented out module-switch-on-port-available, and have this at the end:

```
#load-module module-switch-on-port-available
...
set-default-sink alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
set-default-source alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here... I actually ended up having luck by just disabling USB audio with pavucontrol (package pavucontrol). To do this select the Configuration tab, then set the USB Audio to the Off Profile. Like so:

[image: pavucontrol with USB Audio Profile set to Off]

Now on startup it always selects the built in audio device:

[image: Default Audio Device]