# No sound from speakers using Chromebook

Tags: sound, alsa, chromebook

I need help.

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my Toshiba CB35-B3340, no dual booting.  I have no sound from my speakers or headphones.

When I go to sound settings, the only output device shown is HDMI/Display port.

When I run alsamixer, I only see S/PDEF, there is no master or headphones, etc.

I have tried many of the suggestions posted without success.  I am not too experienced, but will to try.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `aplay -l` to see your playback hardware devices.
2. You should see your device sound card, according to your notebook, look for the one that looks like (Make sure that it refers to *analog* output):

   ```
   card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
   ```
3. Make a new configuration file: `sudo gedit /etc/asound.conf`
4. Put the following and save the file:

   ```
   defaults.pcm.card 0 # Replace with your card number
   defaults.pcm.device 0 # Replace with your device number
   ```
5. Reboot your computer.

Comment: Here's what I see, the card number is 0, the device number is 3, correct?

Comment: john@john-Swanky:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: Generic Digital [Generic Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: chtmax98090 [chtmax98090], device 0: Audio (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: chtmax98090 [chtmax98090], device 1: Deep-Buffer Audio (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Comment: Yes, it's correct, that's the sound card.

Comment: Ok, made the file, saved and rebooted.  Now when I go to the sound settings,  I see that the output device options are now multichannel and analog output-built in audio.  When I test, there is no sound.  Alsamixer for card 0 still only shows S/PDIF, if I choose card 1 I do see master, headphones, etc. is that important?

Comment: I'm not sure, but perhaps it's because the sound output it's related with the _card: 1_, _device: 0_. Try to change the `/etc/asound.conf` with `card number` to: 1 and `device number` to: 0, save and reboot.

Comment: doing that just brings me back to sound settings output device = HDMI/Displayport as my only choice, still no sound output.

Comment: It's important when you choose _card 1_ in alsamixer, it shows you; master, headphones, etc. The problem is that _card 1_ isn't selected by default, so your computer is using the HDMI output as default sound output. So, here is what I think can help you: Go back to the old settings in `/etc/asound.conf`, card number set to: 0, device set to 3, reboot. Then follow to this solution in order to select the analog output as default audio device: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038490/how-do-you-set-a-default-audio-output-device-in-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Ok, now it's getting fuzzy to me.  Which part of this pactl list should I be using?john@john-Swanky:~$ pactl list short sinks
0 alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.stereo-fallback module-alsa-card.c s16le 2ch 44100Hz SUSPENDED

Comment: It's strange that you only have one module. Can you run `cat /proc/asound/cards` and share their output?

Comment: Here is what I havejohn@john-Swanky:~$ pactl list short sinks
0 alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.stereo-fallback module-alsa-card.c s16le 2ch 44100Hz SUSPENDED
john@john-Swanky:~$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0x90714000 irq 91
 1 [chtmax98090    ]: chtmax98090 - chtmax98090
                      GOOGLE-Swanky-1.0

Comment: Well, I don't know if the Chromebook has some special configuration to do in order to make the sound works, but this is what brings to my mind: Go back to `sudo gedit /etc/asound.conf`. Change the two lines that you wrote by: `defaults.pcm.card 0
defaults.ctl.card 0` (no need to reboot) and see if `alsamixer` loads the card that have "master, headphones, etc" by default, and of course check if you have sound (Check that the "Master" have a 00 at the bottom, that means that is not muted, you can mute/unmute by pressing the key M).

Comment: Re-running alsamixer, default showing master etc,- no and no sound.  But on the sound settings, below the output device is what I would call a sound bar (a dashed line) which I can see is fluctuating like the sound signal strength is rising and falling from a youtube I am playing.  Does that mean it's working but muted somehow?

Comment: Oh, btw, I never did not hear from you how to complete the solution using pactl.

Comment: The `pactl` will not work because you only have one module, which is the only one that could be set as default, so there is nothing to do with that, I had been expecting that your output had some _analog_ and _hdmi_ modules. About the sound bar, I can't tell you if that is a good sign or not. Try installing `sudo apt install pavucontrol`, then execute with `pavucontrol`, you will get a GUI to manage the sound more easily, perhaps that helps you.