# How to set the default audio input in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: alsa, microphone, default, input

Thanks to [How do you set a default audio output device in Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038490/how-do-you-set-a-default-audio-output-device-in-ubuntu-18-04) for the output but I can't work out how to set the default input

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [How do you set a default audio output device in Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038490/how-do-you-set-a-default-audio-output-device-in-ubuntu-18-04) for the output bit, but I also have several input devices and wanted to share the solution:

```
pactl list short
```

Will return a list of devices
look for the input device you want. In my case I'm looking for a yeti microphone

```
    0   module-device-restore       
1   module-stream-restore       
2   module-card-restore     
3   module-augment-properties       
4   module-switch-on-port-available     
5   module-switch-on-connect        
6   module-udev-detect      
7   module-bluetooth-policy     
8   module-bluetooth-discover       
9   module-bluez5-discover      
10  module-native-protocol-unix     
11  module-default-device-restore       
12  module-always-sink      
14  module-intended-roles       
15  module-suspend-on-idle      
16  module-console-kit      
17  module-systemd-login        
18  module-position-event-sounds        
19  module-role-cork        
20  module-snap-policy      
21  module-filter-heuristics        
22  module-filter-apply     
23  module-alsa-card    device_id="2" name="pci-0000_0c_00.3" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_0c_00.3" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1"    
24  module-alsa-card    device_id="1" name="usb-Blue_Microphones_Yeti_Stereo_Microphone_797_2018_12_05_58600-00" card_name="alsa_card.usb-Blue_Microphones_Yeti_Stereo_Microphone_797_2018_12_05_58600-00" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1"  
25  module-alsa-card    device_id="0" name="pci-0000_0a_00.1" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_0a_00.1" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1"    
26  module-alsa-card    device_id="3" name="usb-046d_0821_BECDCE90-00" card_name="alsa_card.usb-046d_0821_BECDCE90-00" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1"  
27  module-x11-publish  display=:1 xauthority=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority 
28  module-x11-cork-request display=:1 xauthority=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority 
29  module-x11-xsmp display=:1 xauthority=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority session_manager=local/steev-desktop:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/2648,unix/steev-desktop:/tmp/.ICE-unix/2648 
1   alsa_output.pci-0000_0c_00.3.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
2   alsa_output.usb-Blue_Microphones_Yeti_Stereo_Microphone_797_2018_12_05_58600-00.analog-stereo   module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
5   alsa_output.pci-0000_0a_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1 module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
1   alsa_output.pci-0000_0c_00.3.analog-stereo.monitor  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
2   alsa_output.usb-Blue_Microphones_Yeti_Stereo_Microphone_797_2018_12_05_58600-00.analog-stereo.monitor   module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
3   alsa_input.usb-Blue_Microphones_Yeti_Stereo_Microphone_797_2018_12_05_58600-00.analog-stereo    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
4   alsa_input.usb-046d_0821_BECDCE90-00.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 32000Hz   SUSPENDED
7   alsa_output.pci-0000_0a_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1.monitor module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
0   module-systemd-login.c  (null)
4   module-x11-xsmp.c   (null)
5   protocol-native.c   gnome-shell
8   protocol-native.c   gsd-media-keys
11  protocol-native.c   spotify
12  protocol-native.c   chrome
16  protocol-native.c   python3.8
17  protocol-native.c   pactl
0   alsa_card.pci-0000_0c_00.3  module-alsa-card.c
1   alsa_card.usb-Blue_Microphones_Yeti_Stereo_Microphone_797_2018_12_05_58600-00   module-alsa-card.c
2   alsa_card.pci-0000_0a_00.1  module-alsa-card.c
3   alsa_card.usb-046d_0821_BECDCE90-00 module-alsa-card.c
```

In the list I can find the mic I'm looking for:

```
alsa_input.usb-Blue_Microphones_Yeti_Stereo_Microphone_797_2018_12_05_58600-00.analog-stereo
```

I can set it as the default device:

```
pactl set-default-source alsa_input.usb-Blue_Microphones_Yeti_Stereo_Microphone_797_2018_12_05_58600-00.analog-stereo
```

and if you add that command line to startup apps then you should be golden