# How to remove an audio output device from my computer?

Tags: drivers, sound, hdmi, 21.04

I am using Displaylink driver to use my Dell D3100 dock for my 2 external monitors. But in my sound profile, whenever I boot my laptop or disconnect from my headphones, my computer reverts to the Dock audio as its default audio output device. Its incredibly annoying. I don't want to demove my Displaylink driver as a result but how can I get rid of this?

```
~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3266 Analog [ALC3266 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Dock [Dell D3100 USB3.0 Dock], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio] <-- This is the problem
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternative solution that might help you. I presume you are using Gnome. You may try the Gnome shell extension [Sound input and output device chooser.](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/906/sound-output-device-chooser/)
In the settings of the extension, you have the option to hide the devices.

Comment: I am using wayland on 21.04

Comment: If you're looking for something that is not shown in the classic audio settings, but is shown by `aplay -l` - this will not display it. It's just a shortcut for the regular settings.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the default sound device with something like [How do you set a default audio output device in Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038490/how-do-you-set-a-default-audio-output-device-in-ubuntu-18-04)

1. Run: `pactl list short sinks`
2. Note the device name you want to use as default
3. Try to run: `pactl set-default-sink <Your_Device_Name>`.
   This should work without giving you an error message.
4. Open the application "Startup Applications" (Should be preinstalled on Ubuntu)
5. Click on "Add"
6. Give your startup item a name
7. Copy your command from above into the command field: `pactl set-default-sink 'Your-Device-Name'`
8. Click on "Save".

`pactl list short sources` and `pactl set-default-source <Your_Device_Name>` may also be needed.

As per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1038492/226614), it may also work editing `/etc/pulse/default.pa` to add

```
### Make some devices default
set-default-sink <Your_Device no. or name>
set-default-source <Your_Device no. or name>
```

Perhaps the possible change in numbers mentioned in the answers in the link force the need for a name.
And you may need to comment line `load-module module-switch-on-connect` prepending a `#`.