# App (irium webcam ) changes default audio settings every startup

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone, webcam

Whenever I install [irium webcam](https://iriun.com/) in my pc (i tested with ubuntu 21.10 and pop OS) it changes my default audio input and output source every time I boot my PC. I tried running a startup script with `set-default-sink` and `set-default-source` as most of the thread [like this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/1207638/1547150) suggests, but for some reason, it doesn't work (but when I manually run the script in the terminal, for a strange reason, it change without any problem).

Is there a way to set fix this??

Comment: *I tried running a startup script* What exactly you wrote in this script? Page you linked has many hints.

Comment: I edited the question to link to the answer with the script I ran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with another way:

paste this in a file with a ".sh" extension inside /home/

```
#!/bin/bash
pactl set-default-sink **Your-Device-Name**
```

give the execution auth

```
chmod u+x /home/<yoursession>/<fileyoucreated>.sh
```

and fill the path textbox with these file location in the autostart config.

Remember deactivate this option when you want to not use those device anymore.