# Irium webcam Initialization failed

Tags: webcam, modprobe, desktop-apps

Besides [this other problem I had with irium webcam on linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1377952/app-irium-webcam-changes-default-audio-settings-every-startup), when we close irium webcam and try to open it again we get the message:
[image]

Running this command doesn't make the app work. The only way to get iriun to work again is to reboot the computer.

When I run it directly from terminal `iriunwebcam`, the terminal doesn't show me any error message or any message at all, just opens the application GUI.

Does anyone knows how I could fix that?

## Edit

I'm using Ubuntu 21.10 and I remember having the same problem using the Pop OS 20.xx (don't remember the other numbers).

Comment: @guiverc maybe it is Iriun webcam v2.6

Comment: The deb-package with Iriun webcam v2.6 really exists in the wild - see https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=iriunwebcam-bin . So we need to determine Ubuntu version and steps done.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 21.10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like each time we face this error with iriunwebcam,

we have do a "cleanup" of v4l2loopback device running:

```
sudo rmmod v4l2loopback; 
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback exclusive_caps=1
```

This works ubuntu 22+ version too.