# Setting a persistent default audio output

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I am trying to set my default audio output to be over Display Port.
I've already tried following the settings described in [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1038492/1025347) thread.

The main issue is that my preferred audio output doesn't show up when I run `pactl list short sinks`. I am able to manually add it via the following, however this doesn't work consistently:

```
pactl load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:0,8
pactl set-default-sink alsa_output.hw_0_8
```

I have tried adding the above lines (without `pactl` at the front) to `~/.config/pulse/defaults.pa` which hasn't worked.
I have tried removing `~/.config/pulse/defaults.pa` and adding those lines to `/etc/pulse/defaults.pa` which causes the correct speaker to be used after a restart before I am logged in consistently, but as soon as I log in, the computer switches to the wrong speaker.
I have tried adding the above lines to my `~/.bashrc` file, but the correct speaker only is used after I launch a terminal.
I have tried adding them to `~/.profile` which caused an error to occur at login forcing me to revert the file in a tty.

Is there some way to make this work consistently on boot every time?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by adding the following to my `~/.profile` file:

```
/usr/bin/pactl load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:0,8 2> /dev/null
/usr/bin/pactl set-default-sink alsa_output.hw_0_8 2> /dev/null
```

It is important to note that not having the `2> /dev/null` on each of those lines is what causes the system to display an error message at login and stop functioning.
I believe, with my limited Linux knowledge, this is because an error is raised in the `~/.profile` which causes Ubuntu to think the login failed for some reason and refuses to let you login.

(if that does happen, switch to a tty by pressing `Ctrl+Alt+F3` or another F-key if F3 doesn't work, which should open a terminal-like session. Log in there, modify your `~/.profile` file to not produce errors with your terminal editor of choice, save, and reboot.