# Headphones don't work the first time when the computer is booted. After booting, if I plug them out and plug them back in, only then they work

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, sound, 22.04, headphones

I have Ubuntu 22.04 installed side-by-side with Windows 10 on a Dell Precision 3560. On Windows 10, when I boot in with the headphones plugged in, they work just fine. But that is not the case when I boot into Ubuntu 22.04 and I have to plug them out and back in. I remember this being an issue in Ubuntu 20.04 as well and it seems to not have been fixed.

Comment: Probably, Ubuntu loses the output device settings. You should be able to change Output Device in Settings -> Sound. Or use this [gnome shell extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/906/sound-output-device-chooser/) to change from the menu.

Comment: Okay that worked but how do I tell Ubuntu to set it to headphones when I boot the system with the headphone jack plugged in?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you set a default audio output device in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038490/how-do-you-set-a-default-audio-output-device-in-ubuntu)