# No sound from line-in

Tags: sound

I have two computers that I want to have coming through the same speakers, I bought a cable, which I connected from the headphone jack on the one computer to the line-in jack on the other.

I know sound is coming out of the headphone jack (confirmed by using headphones).  But when I plug the cord into the line-in, I can't get it to output the signal that's coming in on line-in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may be able to redirect the line-in to your sound card output by using gnome-alsamixer (`sudo apt-get install gnome-alsamixer` in case you don't have it).

Just enable the Line option and you should get the input sound redirected to your sound card's output.

I kind of have the same problem, but instead of redirecting to the sound card's output, I'd like to redirect to my USB headphone's output (which contains a separate sound card).

Comment: Whoohoo!   That did it.  Not sure why the gnome mixer worked when the others didn't, but thanks!

Comment: Works nice. I'm starting to give up on the sound settings app. All sound problems I had were solved using alsamixer.