# S/PDIF audio input - how to use it?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

Ubuntu 16.04, USB turntable (yeah, old guy with 300+ vinyl LPs) and the S/PDIF source appears as an input in the sound mixer, even shows the audio levels dancing around as the album plays, and no, its not muted, but I cant seem to coax any sound out of the output.  I can get audio out of other stuff (Pithos and youtube etc) but cant seem to get the audio from the turntable.

I have reloaded alsa and checked the mixer, but can't seem to determine what's wrong.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: If the turntable is connected through USB, what has S/PDIF to do with it? Anyway, if your hardware does not already have a connection between the input and the output (and it sounds like you have two entirely separate devices), then you have to record+playback in software (see [this old question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2719/how-do-i-output-my-audio-input)).

Comment: An S/PDIF device seems to appear and disappear associated with the USB connection.  So I had assumed that was the turntable USB.

Comment: LSUSB identifies it as "Bus 001 Device 002: ID 08bb:29c0 Texas Instruments PCM2900C Audio CODEC" and pactl identifies it as "Bus 001 Device 002: ID 08bb:29c0 Texas Instruments PCM2900C Audio CODEC"